# Spring Studio 3.8.4 won't start up

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I'm running windows 7. When I double click on STS.exe, then this is the error message I get.

[image: STS error message]

I uninstalled all JRE/JDKs, downloaded the latest one (v8 u131), and manually added the -vm line below.

STS.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms40m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-Xverify:none
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Xmx768m
```

Comment: Are you running 32-bit ***or*** 64-bit Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if you go to https://spring.io/tools/sts it will give you the 32bit version of eclipse by default.

I needed to go to https://spring.io/tools/sts/all and specifically find the 64bit version of eclipse (STS) to match my JDK which is 64bit.

Eclipse error detection/reporting could easily be improved to save a lot of unnecesary grief. And the Spring website could be improved to offer both 64bit and 32 bit links from the download page so that the decision/distinction is obvious.